# Repository files location in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, repository

I just finished a project using MVC. I'm wondering where is the correct location to put Repository files. I'm not sure if to put it with the view model since the view is using it or to locate it with the controller since the work is be doing there.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more?..

Comment: Repository files with linq queries.